# Don't run cucumber feature but add it to serenity reports

Tags: java, cucumber-serenity

I use Serenity framework in my project for selenium integration testing. I use Screenplay pattern.

I have two features in one folder and each feature contains two scenarios. I would like to ignore whole feature, but when I add `@Ignore` annotation on feature level both features are ignored. When I add `@Ignore` to each scenario runner ignores some steps, but runs step with RestTemplate get request and fail because of skipped previous step.

**How can I force serenity do not run all scenarios in feature but show it in reports?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Ignored tests are marked as suspended and runs but with mocked web driver usage. I had to add **StepEventBus.getEventBus().currentTestIsSuspended()** check before my REST requests.

2) @Ignored annotation works unexpected for me. I've added **@Unimplemented** annotation and process it in defifnitions before hook.

```
@Before
public void setTheStage(final Scenario scenario) {
    final StepEventBus eventBus = StepEventBus.getEventBus();
    if (scenario.getSourceTagNames().contains("@Unimplemented") && !eventBus.currentTestIsSuspended()) {
        eventBus.suspendTest(TestResult.IGNORED);
    }
```